# How to create a profile with profile points at discrete altitude intervalls, e.g. each 10 m

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, terrain, saga

In both SAGA and QGIS theres a profile-from-line-function that does a nice job of creating profiles. But there's no way to control the altitude spacing.

Any ideas for workflows that would allow me to achieve a profile (river as line-shape on a DEM-layer), with individual profile-points situated only at discrete altitude-intervalls of 10 m ? Of course profile points will need to contain information on segment-length and altidude...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: By altitude you want a profile? Perhaps you mean at certain intervals. like every 10 feet. you can find a densify tool in toolbox @ 10.0.  l'm pretty certain saga has a densify tool also.

Answer (score 1):

From the DEM, make a vector layer with 10m contour lines. Now intersect the river line-shape with the contour lines.